# Text file into an array?

Tags: php

In [php](/questions/tagged/php) how can I read a text file and get each line into an array?

I found this code which does it, somewhat, but looks for a `=` sign and I need to look for a new line:

```
<?PHP
$file_handle = fopen("dictionary.txt", "rb");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
  $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
  $parts = explode('=', $line_of_text);
  print $parts[0] . $parts[1]. "<BR>";
}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Comment: @jasondavis - why would you do that the long way? Just use 'file'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you could just replace the `'='` with a `"\n"` if the only difference is that you're looking for a newline.

However, a more direct way would be to use the `file()` function:

```
$lines = file("dictionary.txt");
```

That's all there is to it!

Answer (score 5):

Use php's [file](http://www.php.net/file) function:

> file — Reads entire file into an array

Example:

```
$lines = file('dictionary.txt');
echo $lines[0]; //echo the first line
```

Comment: @Karim: you have to sell it. From the function's documentation: "Reads an entire file into an array."

Comment: @Telemachus - I'm aware of that, it is what I use 'edit' for.

Comment: @Karim: fair enough (and I was kidding - just my way of saying "This looks like the answer to me...").

Comment: @Telemachus - :) that would make your sense of humor similar to mine.

Answer (score 0):

So, use the character for a newline instead of the '='

```
'\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using '=', use '\n'.

Example (also strips '\r' characters, for files which use '\r\n' as their line delimiter):

```
<?PHP
$file_handle = fopen("dictionary.txt", "rb");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
$line_of_text = str_replace('\r', '', $line_of_text);
$parts = explode('\n', $line_of_text);
print $parts[0] . $parts[1]. "<BR>";
}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Note: This code example won't work on files which use '\r' by itself to specify newlines.