# How to get text from file into array in php

Tags: php

I have text file with some stuff that i would like to put into array. That text file has one value per line. How do i put each line into array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338158/text-file-into-an-array

Answer (score 23, accepted):

use the [file()](http://php.net/file) function - easy!

```
$lines=file('file.txt');
```

If you want to do some processing on each line, it's not much more effort to read it line  by line with [fgets()](http://php.net/fgets)...

```
$lines=array();
$fp=fopen('file.txt', 'r');
while (!feof($fp))
{
    $line=fgets($fp);

    //process line however you like
    $line=trim($line);

    //add to array
    $lines[]=$line;

}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: You can also pass  FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES as the second parameter to avoid the trailing newline in each array element.

Answer (score 1):

use file()

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$fileArr = file("yourfile.txt")
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Answer (score 0):

[`file`](http://docs.php.net/file) will return an array of the file content where each element corresponds to one line of the file (with line ending character seqence).

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines = file('file.txt');
```

[Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use file().

```
<?php
$file_arr = file(/path/file);
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Line #{$line_num}: " . $line;
}
?>
```

[php.net file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)