# Beginner Help: Reading data from file and importing into existing array

Tags: php, jquery

I'm very new to PHP, and as a challenge am trying to make a little inventory control script.  The idea is to have the amount remaining of each item be defined through a PHP array, and then be imported into a javascript array for dynamic DOM insertion.  The amount remaining of each item sits in a .ini file on the server.

This currently works with the below commented OUT code, but obviously I am defining the array values statically within the page:

```
<?php

//$quantity = fopen("quantity.ini", "w") or die("Its broked");
$quant = file("quantity.ini");
//$quant = array();
//$quant[0] = 13;
//$quant[1] = 90;

echo "var uniforms = ["                         ;
echo    "{"                                     ;
echo    "\"item\"   :   \"Item1\",             ";
echo    "\"descr\"  :   \"Blue Hat\",          ";
echo    "\"size\"   :   \" 6-12 \",            ";
echo    "\"colour\" :   \"Black/Blue/Green\",  ";
echo    "\"img\"    :   \" \",                 ";
echo    "\"quant\"  :   \"" . $quant[0] . "\"  ";
echo    "},"                                    ;
echo    "{"                                     ;
echo    "\"item\"   :   \"Item2\",             ";
echo    "\"descr\"  :   \"Black Hat\",         ";
echo    "\"size\"   :   \" Large \",           ";
echo    "\"colour\" :   \"Black\",         ";
echo    "\"img\"    :   \" \",                 ";
echo    "\"quant\"  :   \"" . $quant[1] . "\"  ";
echo    "},"                                    ;
echo "]"                                        ;

for ($i=0; $i < count($quant); $i++) 
    {
        fwrite($quantity, $quant[$i] . PHP_EOL);
    }
fclose($quantity);
?>
```

I know that I don't need to echo the entire Javascript array, whoops :)
I had thought that each line of the file would be brought into a an array called $quant, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372816/how-to-get-text-from-file-into-array-in-php) post.

The INI file, with the commented code invoked and the file() function removed properly writes to the .ini file as whatever values I modify quant[0] and quant[ 1] too.

Answer (score 0):

Write out Jason using json_encode, JavaScript will read that fine, then you can get rid of most of your code

Comment: You're right, a quick look at josn_encode does look more efficient.  Still doesn't help me with modifying a value within a file though :(

Comment: What you mean "modifying value within a file", can you ask the question again

Answer (score 0):

I realize the OP is new to PHP, etc...

But... the correct answer is:   use a database, not a flat file.
it's relatively easy to set up a MySQL or SQLite db

Sorry